# Setting up a Django project on an Apache server

Tags: python, django, apache

I've started a project which I intend to set up on an Apache2 server running Ubuntu. I've created the skeleton of the Django project locally and pushed it to a repo on bitbucket. A friend who provided the server told me that Digital Ocean tutorials may be a good start, so I've been using [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/100) to set up wsgi. I deviated slightly from the wording and steps of the tutorial so I'll run through how I did it.

1. I created a directory at the path `~/public_html/clupus.com` and changed into it.
2. I already had a previous skeleton so I cloned it into the current directory. The path now looked like `~/public_html/clupus.com/clupus` where clupus is a directory containing the project files (manage.py etc.)
3. I created a new virtual host file at `/etc/apache2/sites-available/clupus.com` which contained the following definition:

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
       ServerName clupus.com
       ServerAlias www.clupus.com
       WSGIScriptAlias / /home/ubuntu/public_html/clupus.com/clupus.wsgi
   </VirtualHost>
   ```
4. I then created the actual wsgi file at `~/public_html/clupus.com/clupus.wsgi` which contained the following configuration:

   ```
   import os
   import sys
   sys.path.append('~/public_html/clupus.com')
   os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'clupus.clupus.settings'
   import django.core.handlers.wsgi 
   application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
   ```
5. Finally I did `sudo a2ensite clupus.com` followed by `sudo service apache2 reload`. When I went to access the URL at which the server was located I was met with the default welcome page. Assuming I had to de-activate the default page I did `sudo a2dissite 000-default` followed by a reload which now, understandably, gives me a 500 error.

My question is what is the URL I use to access my Django project? I feel like I've set everything up correctly and I'm just not pointing to the right URL.

Also, in the line `os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'clupus.clupus.settings'` should it be `clupus.clupus.settings` or just `clupus.settings` given the hierarchy is `~/public_html/clupus.com/clupus/clupus/settings.py`

Comment: Not related to your problem, but you shouldn't be putting your Django code in `public_html`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to directory list that you posted and your comments:

```
ubuntu@ip-10-137-27-87:~/public_html/clupus.com$ ls ~/public_html/clupus.com/ -la
total 16
drwxrwxr-x 3 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Jan 14 11:13 .
drwxrwxr-x 3 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Jan 14 10:38 ..
drwxr-xr-x 7 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Jan 14 10:43 clupus
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu  219 Jan 14 14:09 clupus.wsgi
ubuntu@ip-10-137-27-87:~/public_html/clupus.com$
```

you should change full path here (you can use [`os.path.expanduser`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser) to convert `~` (tilde) to home path):

```
#sys.path.append('~/public_html/clupus.com'
sys.path.append('/home/ubuntu/public_html/clupus.com/clupus')
```

To fix this `ImportError: Could not import settings 'clupus.settings'` check var `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE`. Path `'clupus.settings'` should work after changing sys.path (supposed that `settings.py` located in `/home/ubuntu/public_html/clupus.com/clupus/clupus` directory):

```
#os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'clupus.clupus.settings'
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'clupus.settings'
```

Comment: I've done that and reloaded Apache. Whenever I visit the IP it still gives me the internal server error. Should I be visiting a sub-directory of the IP?

Comment: `ImportError: Could not import settings 'clupus.settings'`

Comment: I think it's looking for a python model called com inside clupus instead of referencing it as a whole. I have never faced such a problem, but do try this: `'"clupus.com".settings'` (notice the " and ' difference)

Comment: I think adding ~/public_html/clupus.com/clupus to you python path will solve your problem.

Comment: None of the suggestions have worked sadly. For clarification the absolute path of settings.py is `~/public_html/clupus.com/clupus/clupus/settings.py`.

Comment: @Nanor try change path: sys.path.append('/home/ubuntu/public_html/clupus.com/clupus')

Comment: Yep! That worked, thanks! If you could add it to your answer I'll mark it correct. :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure apache user have permission to ~/public_html/clupus.com ?

Could you do

```
ls ~/public_html -la
ls ~/public_html/clupus.com -la
```

Comment: sudo usermod -a -G www-data ubuntu

Comment: The problem has been fixed above. Thanks though!